# Como fazer o envio de e-mail simultâneo com laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, foreach

Preciso que meu sistema faça o envio simultâneo de e-mail para tds os e-mails que estiverem no bd. Seguindo o código abaixo ele só envia o 1º e-mail da lista e ainda envia errado. Envia pro spam. E o msm código eu uso no form d contato que envia para caixa de entrada perfeitamente. Ms sem o foreach.

```
public function sendEmail()
{
    $emails = $this->emailRepository->EmailByStatus();
    $description = 'teste';
    $subject = 'teste';

    $data = array('description'=>$description, 'subject'=>$subject);

       foreach ($emails as $email) 
       {

        $send = Mail::send('email.email-multiple', $data, function($message) use($emails, $description, $subject)
        {
            $message->to($email)->subject($subject);

                $message->from('email@fantasia');

        });

     }
        if(!$send)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

Tbm tentei assim:

```
foreach($emails as $email)
{
     $message->to($email);
}
```

Tbm só envia o 1º  e errado tbm. E qnd envia.

O que tem de errado no código acima?

Comment: Como eu excluo a pergunta? kkkk Sr Admins, pode fechar. Eu troquei o to pelo from.

Answer (score 1):

No `use` você adicionou `$emails` e não `$email` (sem `s`):

```
 use($emails, $description, $subject)
```

O certo provavelmente deveria ser isto:

```
function($message) use($email, $description, $subject)
```

Assim:

```
$send = Mail::send('email.email-multiple', $data, function($message) use($email, $description, $subject)
{
    $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
    $message->from('email@fantasia');
});
```

Mas se o corpo do e-mail e titulo são todos iguais, você poderia passar `$emails` (com "s") diretamente sem precisar do `foreach` (pelo seu código suponho que seja a versão 5.1 ou 5.2):

```
public function sendEmail()
{
    $emails = $this->emailRepository->EmailByStatus();
    $description = 'teste';
    $subject = 'teste';

    $data = array('description' => $description, 'subject' => $subject);

    $send = Mail::send('email.email-multiple', $data, function($message) use ($emails, $description, $subject)
    {
        $message->to($emails)->subject($subject);
        $message->from('email@fantasia');
    });

    if(!$send)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Se quiser que os destinatários não se enxerguem então use `bcc` (*Blind carbon copy* ou *Cópia oculta*), assim:

```
public function sendEmail()
{
    $emails = $this->emailRepository->EmailByStatus();
    $description = 'teste';
    $subject = 'teste';

    $data = array('description' => $description, 'subject' => $subject);

    $send = Mail::send('email.email-multiple', $data, function($message) use ($emails, $description, $subject)
    {
        $message->bcc($emails)->subject($subject);
        $message->from('email@fantasia');
    });

    if(!$send)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```